# web.config transform - insert file contents

Tags: web-config, web-config-transform

We're working with `web.config` files in a fairly complex Visual Studio solution, I'd like to be able to insert the contents of a file (that is not a web config) into the `web.config`, is this possible to do with transforms?

The purpose of this is to have a global configuration for two projects, one of which is a `WebApi` project and the other is an `MVC` project. The configuration that we have for both is fairly involved and it will be a challenge to maintain those configs to various deployment environments.